# Why do calls to adduser and groupadd not work when rpm installed?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I added the following "Pre" section to my rpm installer's build.spec.  When I install the rpm no new group or user is created?

If I paste this into a script and run, then it works as expected.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,

-Ed

RHEL 5.2

```
#######################
# pre
#######################
%pre

# This works when run as a script by root.  Why not from the RPM?
if grep ^frontier: /etc/group >> /dev/null ; then
 : # group already exists
else
 %{_sbindir}/groupadd frontier -g 2000
fi

if ! id diagnostics >& /dev/null; then 
 %{_sbindir}/adduser diagnostics -g diaguser -d /home/diagnostics -u 2001 -p secretPassword
 usermod -a -G frontier diagnostics
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`%_sbindir/groupadd`

instead of

`%{_sbindir}`

Check your RPMs after they build with something like mc, extract the pre script and you'll be able to check that your expansion works right.

In fact, %_sbindir is not needed there. If you take a look how RedHat built httpd....rpm you'll see they just use groupadd and useradd without the full path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I am not sure what you mean when you say "check that your expansion works right".  Midnight Commander (mc) is a file manager correct?  Is this similar to using Archive Manager by using it to open the rpm and browse the files it contains? 

My problem was I located the groupadd instructions in the wrong section.  My build spec created a main package plus additional packages.  I intended groupadd to be part of the additional packages but did not understand that I needed to append "-n myAdditionalPackage" to the %pre or %post section.  Sorry for the dumb mistake.
-Ed

Comment: expansion = macro expansion i.e. that %_sbindir is actually expanded to /usr/sbin/ in the scripts written into the RPM.

mc is a file manager, and it I am guessing it is similar to the AM based on what you describe.